# How is 'from/where/select' keywords impemented under the hood in LINQ and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When I type 'from' (in a [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) query) after importing [System.Linq namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx), it is understood as a keyword. How does this magic happen?

Is 'from' a extension method on some type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In practice, yes - LINQ keywords map to extension methods. But actually, it is more interesting; it is literally as though the compiler substitutes directly for a few key methods, i.e.

```
var qry = from cust in db.Customers
          where cust.IsActive
          select cust;
```

becomes:

```
var qry = db.Customers.Where(cust => cust.IsActive);
```

(if we had a non-trivial select, it would add .Select(...some projection...)

Different LINQ kewords map to different methods - i.e. there is OrderBy, GroupBy, ThenBy, OrderByDescending, etc.

In the case of `IEnumerable<T>`/`IQueryable<T>`, this then resolves these via extension methods (typically courtesy of `Enumerable`/`Queryable`)- however, if your queryable objects declared their own Where/OrderBy/etc then these would get used in preference.

Jon Skeet covers this a lot more in the latter parts of [C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/). I've also seen [an example of Jon's](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/29/odd-query-expressions.aspx) where he discusses some really bizarre implications of this - such as calling static methods on a type.

Comment: Leaving out the Select() is just an optimization. It still requires a Select() even when it's a call to Select(x=>x);

Comment: Yes, but it is an optimization that it does do. It'll leave the Select in if you have "var qry = from x in y select x" - i.e. becomes "var qry = y.Select(x=>x)" - however, in many of the other typical simple cases it will omit it (unless you have a non-trivial projection).

Answer (score 4):

Marc Gravell has [answered the question admirably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190936/how-is-fromwhereselect-keywords-impemented-under-the-hood-clinq#190948), but I can't resist the temptation to mention the [weird things you can do with query expressions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/29/odd-query-expressions.aspx). The compiler really doesn't care very much how it finds a "Select" member, or "Where" etc.

The way that the compiler translates the code into "C# 3.0 without query expressions" before doing normal compilation is really beautiful - it's a wonderful way of introducing new functionality into the language but only having an impact in one isolated portion of the specification.

Comment: Already linked it in ;-p (I just needed a few seconds to track it down...)

Comment: "your friendly tag-team MVPs" ;-p

Answer (score -1):

"from" is a language keyword (just like "if" or "foreach").

You don't even need to import System.Linq to use "from", but you need to use 3.5 framework.

Comment: You don't even need the 3.5 framework - you just need a suitable set of methods. For instance, LINQBridge works against .NET 2.0, and you can write C# 3.0 against it.

Comment: No, you don't. You need C# 3.0, which isn't the same thing. LINQBridge, for example, brings LINQ-to-Objects into .NET 2.0 with C# 3.0.

Comment: "from" is not a language keyword. It is a context-dependent syntax element. The difference becomes clear when you realise that you can name a variable "from" (without an @), but you can't name a variable "if" or "foreach" (unless you add an @).